# Link pages by using mui react drawer

Tags: routes, material-ui

In my application i need to render a login page without the drawer and render rest of the pages inside the drawer. So I created Home.jsx file which contains the drawer and put my routes inside of it. The issue is i couldn't render the pages properly.

This is my App.js file.

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/users" element={<Home />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
</ThemeProvider>
```

This is my Home.jsx file

```
      <Drawer>
        <Accordion className="sidebar-accordian">
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<SouthEastIcon className="arrow-icon" />}
            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
            id="panel1a-header"
          >
            <Typography style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <img style={{ marginRight: '10px' }} src={users} />
              <Link to="/users" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}>
                Users
              </Link>
            </Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Typography>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
              malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
            </Typography>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      </Drawer>

      <Box>
        <Toolbar />

        <div className="main-box-component-inner-div">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<div>Home Page</div>} />
            <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Box>
```

Above code gives me the Home.jsx content to '/users' too. But if i remove `<Route path="/users" element={<Home />} />` from App.js it gives me blank screen for '/users' route. When i edit it as `<Route path="/users" element={<Users/>} />` in App.js it renders Users.jsx content but without the drawer. Please help me to display my Users.jsx file inside the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to implement Public and Protected Routes concept and use Outlet component of RRDv6. Here's a basic guide for Protected Routes  from [shirisha95's](https://medium.com/@shirisha95/react-router-v6-simplified-protected-routes-85b209326a55)  medium post.